# What versions of Sync Framework are compatible with Windows Mobile 6.5?

Tags: synchronization, compact-framework, compatibility, microsoft-sync-framework, windows-mobile-6.5

We have an app developed for a Windows Mobile 6.5 device that uses Microsoft Sync Framework 1.0. What other framework versions are compatible with Mobile 6.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.0 is the only supported version if you're running the older SqlCeClientSyncSyncProvider. Your only other option on Sync Fx is the Sync Framework Toolkit. other than that, have a look at Zumero.